# mysql access denied for user ERROR 1045

Tags: mysql, freebsd

I'm trying to user mysql on my machine, but I can't access the program.

I added configuration using `mysql_config_editor` as such:

```
mysql_config_editor set --login-path=client --user=root -p --host=localhost
```

and when i do a print i get:

```
[client]
user = root
password = *****
host = localhost
```

But when I try to connect to mysql, I get the following error

```
#mysql -u root -p
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using passowd: YES)
```

And when I try to connect like this, i get:

```
#mysql -u root -p -h127.0.0.1
ERROR 1130 (HY000): Host 'localhost' is not allowed to this MYSQL server
```

Every other answer I found was to do a SQL command. But i can't get inside the shell to do it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Have you already tried using the --skip-grant-tables option? If you have, and it doesn't allow you to access the mysql shell, go into your mysql installation folder and open *my.ini* file (*my.cnf* for most Linux distros). Inside it you'll find a mysqld tag, add `skip-grant-tables` underneath it and restart your mysql server. You'll be able to access your shell and therefrom edit the rights/privileges.

Comment: I don't have this option, I don't even have mysql config directory :|